# How to mint a collection of NFTs using mintBatch function of ERC1155 with custom URI for each collection?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc1155

I'm trying to mint multiple NFTs using `mintBatch` from the ERC1155 contract. However, I want to use a custom URI whenever I call `mintBatch` function.

**Example:** I mint collection1 of 10 NFTs by calling the `mintBatch` function with a URI. This URI will be the same for all these 10 NFTs in the collection. Next, I want to mint another collection2 of 10 NFTs using the `mintBatch` with a new URI. This URI should be the same for all NFTs of collection2 but should be different from the URI of collection1.

Note: I don't want to have a custom URI for each NFT, but for a collection of NFTs created using `mintBatch` so that all the NFTs in the collection have the same URI.

How to mint a collection of NFTs using the `mintBatch` function of ERC1155 in such a way that each collection should have its custom URI?

Comment: I don't have an answer, I also wonder too. Don't mind me following this question.